# Django: python manage.py runserver exits with ‘Performing system checks, what is the possible issue?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on a django project and have been using `python manage.py runserver` to spin up my development local server, but it just started exiting at `Performing system checks`. This is the first time i am encountering such issue, have any one experienced this issue before, please how do i go about it?

```
C:\Users\Destiny Franks\Desktop\ecommerce_prj>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...


C:\Users\pc-name\Desktop\ecommerce_prj>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

C:\Users\pc-name\Desktop\ecommerce_prj>
```

This is how everything looks, it does not show any error message or issue, just breaks off and return to the cmd

### update

My Settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for ecommerce_prj project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages

from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-@uebu%zn!ghp@b05*c+jgrxv!d)p(iw3=tl*&24m5)&^u^gq@)'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'jazzmin',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',

    # Custom
    'store',
    'core',
    'addons',
    'userauths',
    'vendor',
    'reports',

    # Third Party
    'import_export',
    'crispy_forms',
    'mathfilters',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'django_ckeditor_5',
    'taggit',
    'corsheaders',
    "anymail",
    'paypal.standard.ipn',
    'geoip2',
    'django_user_agents',
]



MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_user_agents.middleware.UserAgentMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ecommerce_prj.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'core.context_processor.default',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ecommerce_prj.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

JAZZMIN_SETTINGS = {
    'site_header': "Desphixs Shop",
    'site_brand': "You order, we deliver",
    'site_logo': "assets/imgs/theme/loading.gif",
    'copyright': "desphixs-shop.com",
    "order_with_respect_to": ["store", 'vendor', "addons" , 'core' ,'userauths']

}

LOGIN_URL = "userauths:sign-in"

# LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "core:index"

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "userauths:sign-in"

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'userauths.User'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'




STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = 'test_keys'
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = 'test_keys'
STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID = 'test_keys'

PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID = 'test_keys-test_keys'
PAYPAL_SECRET_ID = 'test_keys-test_keys-Vy'

PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL = 'test_keys@gmail.com'
PAYPAL_TEST = True

GEOIP_PATH =os.path.join('geoip')

MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.ERROR: 'danger',
}

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'


customColorPalette = [
    {"color": "hsl(4, 90%, 58%)", "label": "Red"},
    {"color": "hsl(340, 82%, 52%)", "label": "Pink"},
    {"color": "hsl(291, 64%, 42%)", "label": "Purple"},
    {"color": "hsl(262, 52%, 47%)", "label": "Deep Purple"},
    {"color": "hsl(231, 48%, 48%)", "label": "Indigo"},
    {"color": "hsl(207, 90%, 54%)", "label": "Blue"},
]

ANYMAIL = {
    # (exact settings here depend on your ESP...)
    "MAILGUN_API_KEY": "key-test_keys",
    "MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN": 'test_keys.mailgun.org',  # your Mailgun domain, if needed
}

FROM_EMAIL = "test_keys@gmail.com"
EMAIL_BACKEND = "anymail.backends.mailgun.EmailBackend"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "test_keys@gmail.com"  
SERVER_EMAIL = "test_keys@gmail.com"  



CKEDITOR_5_CONFIGS = {
    "default": {
        "toolbar": [
            "heading",
            "|",
            "bold",
            "italic",
            "link",
            "bulletedList",
            "numberedList",
            "blockQuote",
            "imageUpload"
        ],
    },
    "comment": {
        "language": {"ui": "en", "content": "en"},
        "toolbar": [
            "heading",
            "|",
            "bold",
            "italic",
            "link",
            "bulletedList",
            "numberedList",
            "blockQuote",
        ],
    },
    "extends": {
        "language": "en",
        "blockToolbar": [
            "paragraph",
            "heading1",
            "heading2",
            "heading3",
            "|",
            "bulletedList",
            "numberedList",
            "|",
            "blockQuote",
        ],
        "toolbar": [
            # "heading",
            # "codeBlock",
            # "|",
            
            # "|",
            "bold",
            "italic",
            # "link",
            "underline",
            "strikethrough",
            # "code",
            # "subscript",
            # "superscript",
            # "highlight",
            "|",
            "bulletedList",
            # "numberedList",
            # "todoList",
            # "|",
            # "outdent",
            # "indent",
            # "|",
            # "blockQuote",
            # "insertImage",
            # "|",
            # "fontSize",
            # "fontFamily",
            # "fontColor",
            # "fontBackgroundColor",
            # "mediaEmbed",
            "removeFormat",
            # "insertTable",
            # "sourceEditing",
        ],
        "image": {
            "toolbar": [
                "imageTextAlternative",
                "|",
                "imageStyle:alignLeft",
                "imageStyle:alignRight",
                "imageStyle:alignCenter",
                "imageStyle:side",
                "|",
                "toggleImageCaption",
                "|"
            ],
            "styles": [
                "full",
                "side",
                "alignLeft",
                "alignRight",
                "alignCenter",
            ],
        },
        "table": {
            "contentToolbar": [
                "tableColumn",
                "tableRow",
                "mergeTableCells",
                "tableProperties",
                "tableCellProperties",
            ],
            "tableProperties": {
                "borderColors": customColorPalette,
                "backgroundColors": customColorPalette,
            },
            "tableCellProperties": {
                "borderColors": customColorPalette,
                "backgroundColors": customColorPalette,
            },
        },
        "heading": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "model": "paragraph",
                    "title": "Paragraph",
                    "class": "ck-heading_paragraph",
                },
                {
                    "model": "heading1",
                    "view": "h1",
                    "title": "Heading 1",
                    "class": "ck-heading_heading1",
                },
                {
                    "model": "heading2",
                    "view": "h2",
                    "title": "Heading 2",
                    "class": "ck-heading_heading2",
                },
                {
                    "model": "heading3",
                    "view": "h3",
                    "title": "Heading 3",
                    "class": "ck-heading_heading3",
                },
            ]
        },
        "list": {
            "properties": {
                "styles": True,
                "startIndex": True,
                "reversed": True,
            }
        },
        "htmlSupport": {
            "allow": [
                {"name": "/.*/", "attributes": True, "classes": True, "styles": True}
            ]
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: have you changed anything in `settings.py`

Comment: yes, i have changed alot of things, but not the default settings? could it be i have changed on the default settings?

Comment: i suggest you share your `settings.py` code as the error may be in there